# convert query syntax with multiple from and ref back to outer

Tags: c#, linq

I'm struggling coming up with the method form of the following query syntax that contains 2 `from` clauses and a selection composed from both.  It's the reference back to the outer `customerid` and `totaldata` that are throwing me.

```
//types
DataPair {
  int key;
  int value;
}
Customer { 
  int customerid { get; set; } 
  int totaldata { get; set; } 
  IEnumerable<DataPair> datapairs { get; set; }
}

var result = from a in customerdata
             from b in a.datapairs
             select new {  a.customerid, a.totaldata, b.key, b.value }
```

Comment: The problem is that `datapairs` is not a single variable, so it can't know which `DataPair` you want.

Comment: @PeterDuniho How is this not a concise, clear question? You must have missed the part where I specified exactly that the problem I'm having is projecting the `customerid` and `totaldata` with `key` and `value`. Was "throwing me" just a too colloquial for your sensibilities? I wasn't aware of a stack meta against colloquial phrasing. If there is one, please share, I'll edit. The title states "convert query syntax"... what could I possibly mean since only two ways to write LINQ exist? I posted what I want converted. I state "dot notation" for clarity. How exactly can I make this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are seeking for the equivalent method syntax for the provided query syntax.

Multiple `from` clauses are known to be mapped to the `SelectMany` extension method. And when the query contains only 2 `from` clauses, it directly maps to the following [`SelectMany` overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534631(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TCollection, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, IEnumerable<TCollection>> collectionSelector,
    Func<TSource, TCollection, TResult> resultSelector
)
```

so the equivalent method syntax would be like this:

```
var result = customerdata.SelectMany(a => a.datapairs,
    (a, b) => new { a.customerid, a.totaldata, b.key, b.value });
```

Comment: Thank you. Apparently some on this site haven't heard of "dot notation" as a reference to this form of LINQ.  I've heard comprehension syntax, method syntax and dot notation.  I guess I used the wrong one.  And your answer wonderfully proves that my question's intent was quite clear.  If you have any suggestions on how to make it better, or more clearly stated or recognizable to the stack community, I'd love to hear from you... as you obviously understand my question in the first place. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @cocogorilla AFAIK there is a consensus that the "official" terms are "query syntax" and "method syntax", but as soon as we understand what are you talking about, there is no problem at all :) But using them will allow you getting better answers (and avoid the fake ones just because the answerer don't understand the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want (which datapair specifically, based on a condition maybe), try this:

```
var result = from a in customerdata
             select new {  a.customerid, a.totaldata, 
                           a.datapairs.Where(*meeting some condition here*).Select(dp => dp.key), 
                           a.datapairs.Where(*meeting another condition here, or the same*).Select(dp => dp.value) }
```

For example:

```
var result = from a in customerdata
             select new {  a.customerid, a.totaldata, 
                           a.datapairs.Where(d => d.key == 5).Select(dp => dp.key), 
                           a.datapairs.Where(d => d.key == 5).Select(dp => dp.value) }
```

If this is not what you want, specify what your condition is and I can provide a helpful example.